# What's the difference between "the seat in front of you" and "the seat in front of yours"?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, differences, grammatical-case, double-possessive

I came across an airline announcement and the following question arose. Which would you say it is **THE** correct sentence, and why?

1. For your comfort and safety, please stow the luggage labelled with the red tag and other small items under the seat in front of **yours**, except for the emergency exists and the first rows.
2. For your comfort and safety, please stow the luggage labelled with the red tag and other small items under the seat in front of **you**, except for the emergency exists and the first rows.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. The seat in question is 'in front of your seat', but while you are sitting in your own seat it is also 'in front of you'. They are simply two different ways of describing the same thing. It has nothing to do with expressions like 'a friend of mine'.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, but I believe that the original intention was "in front of YOU". It sounds a bit more elegant to me.